# Emacs (ipython) inferior python shows strange input numbers

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

In emacs, I use ipython in the inferior python mode with config:

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
    python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt -i")
```

When I edit my .py file, without any input to inferior python, the input number jumps occasionally.

[image: Strange input number]
I suspect that I send some unintentional inputs to the inferior python. But, I don't know how. It happens quite randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completion and other features of the python mode require communication between emacs and the ipython process. This communication is achieved by sending code to the interactive `ipython` inferior shell. These are probably the "unintentional inputs" you are sending.